# gulp-notify: [Error in notifier] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify' not found: notify-send

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-5, gulp

I'm trying to setup Gulp in my install of Laravel 5.1. I've ran then command `npm install` as specified in the Laravel documentation and that's worked fine.

However, when I now run the command `gulp` I get the following message:

```
ubuntu@NAME:/var/www/html/FOLDER# gulp
[14:04:56] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/FOLDER/gulpfile.js
[14:04:56] Starting 'default'...
[14:04:56] Starting 'sass'...
[14:04:56] Running Sass: resources/assets/sass/app.scss
[14:04:56] Finished 'default' after 532 ms
[14:04:56] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compiled!
[14:04:56] Finished 'sass' after 666 ms
[14:04:56] gulp-notify: [Error in notifier] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify'
not found: notify-send
```

Has anyone else encountered the error?

```
gulp-notify: [Error in notifier] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify'
not found: notify-send
```

Thanks

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I've found a resolution to this issue myself. I ran the following commands on my Ubuntu box:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
```

After that, I can now run `gulp` and get the following:

```
ubuntu@NAME:/var/www/html/FOLDER# gulp
[14:06:59] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/FOLDER/gulpfile.js
[14:06:59] Starting 'default'...
[14:06:59] Starting 'sass'...
[14:06:59] Running Sass: resources/assets/sass/app.scss
[14:07:00] Finished 'default' after 736 ms
[14:07:00] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compiled!
[14:07:00] Finished 'sass' after 931 ms
```

All looks good. Hopefully that will be of use to other SO users.

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 8):

For CentOS/Fedora/RedHat 7 users:

```
sudo yum install libnotify
```

(no "-bin")

Answer (score 6):

I have found the following commands, useful:

```
npm install notify-send
```

The problem is gone.

Comment: Solved my problem for windows environment!

Comment: The project is not updated for 10 years now. If you are looking for specific versions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/notify-send/v/0.1.2